# Getting user's info including date joined with Google/YouTube

Tags: php, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

I tried the API provided by Google but I never get the data joined field from the following.

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token={access_token}

```
{
   id: "xxx12212121",
   email: "xxx@gmail.com",
   verified_email: true,
   name: "name",
   given_name: "given",
   family_name: "family",
   link: "",
   picture: "",
   gender: "male",
   locale: "en"
}
```

I get user info from this.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true&access_token={access_token}

```
{
   kind: "youtube#channelListResponse",
   etag: ""m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/z1gqFgh3CSk3IPqbcioKrdSLWC8"",
   pageInfo: {
      totalResults: 1,
      resultsPerPage: 1
   },
   items: [
      {
         kind: "youtube#channel",
         etag: ""m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/ZhbI7F3l_8IFIKdqr4bM1ypv-vI"",
         id: "UCaWN2zhl0zuSdZWW11WcYGg"
      }
   ]
}
```

I get the channel id from this.

What should I include to get the date the YouTube user started or joined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information in the YouTube API is organized in so-called parts. In your example, you requested the `id` part of the channel resource. The property you seek is contained in the `snippet` part and is called `publishedAt`.

So your URL should look like this:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id,snippet&mine=true&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

Notice that you can request multiple parts by comma-separating them. This will get you the following result:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/bFgk_cna5xETz2qMNX9ggxvvny8\"",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/TlIL_94eU05dqfDk52YIjQnlu6c\"",
      "id": "UCaWN2zhl0zuSdZWW11WcYGg",
      "snippet": {
        "title": "Oliver Susano",
        "description": "",
        "publishedAt": "2006-07-04T07:42:01.000Z",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-K24hhru6jNo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/Z9DpkE9NMqM/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-K24hhru6jNo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/Z9DpkE9NMqM/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-K24hhru6jNo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/Z9DpkE9NMqM/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
          }
        },
        "localized": {
          "title": "Oliver Susano",
          "description": ""
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Link to documentation on Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels)

Comment: but from the output you posted it is published date of the video not the date user joined. i already know that procedure where i can get all the videos and other stats i just need the date when the user joined youtube/google.

Comment: No, it is the date that the channel was created. You can see `"kind": "youtube#channel"` which indicates what type the resource is, in this case a channel. There is no info about individual videos in that response whatsoever.

Comment: if what you saying is correct then the published date on each video should be the same but here just to show you it is a date when you uploaded the video. https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCxZFRaweQ1zSJtYK_A4OQJg&maxResults=10&access_token=ya29.GluyBMEq4s6XyRW8Zi3Wr1qf-dqSF5Uy2fji07XAxbvmKtndZNl9ywSa424LQbQOruiCxTHujHroQ6FTIGeFjbUjsV8kfvXVswnc6M9tTS8B-JQDVOMtNQk7TfTD

Comment: ok got it. my fault. i was looking at the video list not the channel info. thanks for the input.

Comment: Glad I could help.